# Why does this "improvement" to this algoirthm not work?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I created an algorithm to solve the following problem statement: 
The problem statement is :

We say that two integers x and y have a variation of at least K, if |x − y| ≥ K (the absolute value of their difference is at least K). Given a sequence of N integers a1,a2,...,aN and K, the total variation count is the number of pairs of elements in the sequence with variation at least K, i.e. it is the size of the set of pairs

```
{(i,j)|1≤i<j≤N and|ai−aj|≥K}
```

code:

```
int n, k, count = 0;
cin >> n >> k;

int v[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> v[i];
}

sort(v, v + n);

for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < n;) {

    if (abs(v[i] - v[j]) >= k) {
        count += (n-j);
        i++;
    }
    else
        j++;
}
cout << count;
return 0; }
```

If we have the input:

```
4 1 // first int is the number of N integers, the second int is the k.
3 1 3 2 // first integers.
```

So my problem is the following: If I want to improve the algorithm by adding j++ under the i++ in the if block, the output changes from 5 (the correct one) to 4. When i test this improvement on papper and it seems to work, but in code it doesn't, why?

Comment: All else aside, `int v[n];` is not valid C++. It's an extension allowed by the GCC compiler, but not by others.

Comment: There's already `j++` before `i++`. When you say you want to add `j++` under `i++`, do you mean you want to increment `j` twice? Then obviously you'd be skipping some elements entirely.

Comment: My bad, the j++ is the improvment, original is only i++

Comment: Also, your existing solution seems wrong to me as well. For example, in your example, if you set `K` to 3 or larger, it seems to me that your loop will never terminate (i.e. bad things will happen when you run off the edge of the array.)

Comment: I edited the code to the original code without the improvement now

Comment: @lomo133: What happens if you run your code with the same array and `K` = 4?

Comment: try it with [0,1,2,10,11,12], K=5

Comment: Yeah I can see that with k = 4 the output is weird, but if it would work I don't get the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I trace the execution with your inputs

without the added j++ associated to the i++ :

```
(abs(v[0] - v[1]) >= k) = 1
    count += (n-1)
(abs(v[1] - v[1]) >= k) = 0
(abs(v[1] - v[2]) >= k) = 1
    count += (n-2)
(abs(v[2] - v[2]) >= k) = 0
(abs(v[2] - v[3]) >= k) = 0
(abs(v[2] - v[4]) >= k) = 1
    count += (n-4)
(abs(v[3] - v[4]) >= k) = 1
    count += (n-4)
result 5
```

if I add j++ in the block containing i++ :

```
(abs(v[0] - v[1]) >= k) = 1
    count += (n-1)
(abs(v[1] - v[2]) >= k) = 1
    count += (n-2)
(abs(v[2] - v[3]) >= k) = 0
(abs(v[2] - v[4]) >= k) = 1
    count += (n-4)
(abs(v[3] - v[5]) >= k) = 1
    count += (n-5)

result 4
```

This is not the same thing, in that case the result is not the same because of the last `count += (n-5)` rather than `count += (n-4)` because of the value of  j

[edit add]

The program to test :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int, char **)
{
#if 0
  int n, k, count = 0;
  cin >> n >> k;

  int v[n];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> v[i];
  }

  sort(v, v + n);
#else
  int n = 4, k = 1;
  int v[] = { 1, 2, 3, 3};
  int count = 0;
#endif

  for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < n;) {
    cout << "(abs(v[" << i << "] - v[" << j << "]) >= k) = " << (abs(v[i] - v[j]) >= k) << endl;
    if (abs(v[i] - v[j]) >= k) {
      cout << "\tcount += (n-" << j << ")" << endl;
      count += (n-j);
      j++;  // THIS LINE IS IN COMMENT OR OUT OF COMMENT
      i++;
    }
    else
      j++;
  }
  cout << count;
  return 0;
}
```

[/edit]

Comment: Thanks it kinda make sense, but can you do the same with the input 1 2 3 3? As the array will be sorted.

Comment: ? I did the execution  with 1 2 3 3

Comment: @lomo133 I added how I did the test, because I am lazy I put values into the program, to not enter them each time